# Convert a regular website to a mobile website

Tags: css, wordpress, blackberry

I have an existing website running in wordpress, and uses a custom headway theme. I want to make it compatible with BlackBerry.

What is the process of making it compatible with a BlackBerry? 
Do I need separate css, or a separate site dedicated just for mobile?

How do I emulate a BlackBerry and debug my css or design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zourtney linked a pretty cool looking plugin, but if you're looking to do this by hand you want to use css3 Media Queries.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

http://www.davidrcole.com/2010/11/make-your-website-mobile-friendly-in-one-night/

For older blackberries - basically anything pre torch I believe you're going to have very shoddy css and JS support, so you'll want to do some testing on an actual device, and use clean semantic html on your page for better rendering.

Comment: wow, yep on the right track and your saving my life. :) thanks! my next problem is simulating black berry, I don't have the device. Do you know how I can test and debug it? i hope there's a firebug. Thanks!

Comment: It's not perfect, but for quick and dirty BB use the Web Dev Toolbar in FF and choose "small screen rendering" under Miscellaneous. This is a good jumping off point at the least

Answer (score 0):

First off, you certainly don't want another site -- that is, you don't want another copy of your database. What you do want is [theme switching](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobile-theme-switcher/) -- found through a quick Google search.

You will want a completely separate Wordpress theme (CSS + html/php). And always be sure that you also include links for mobile users to view the full site (default theme) as well.